# Underline animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, underline

I'm trying to do an animation with hover on a link without success, here's my code:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="border" href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="border" href="#">TOUR</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="border" href="#">CONTACTUS</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".border").hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            borderBottom: '2px solid #3399FF',
            width: '46%'
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2GJrW/3/)

I know it looks very bad but, please help !

I appreciate your consideration.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't included jQuery library...  http://jsfiddle.net/2GJrW/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".border").hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            borderBottom: '2px solid #3399FF',
            width : '46%'
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah sorry, what i really need is to make work a .mouseleave, my mistake.
i tried this but it goes twice every hover: http://jsfiddle.net/2GJrW/10/

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GJrW/11/)...

Answer (score 1):

It works, see that there wasn't loaded jQuery.

See now: http://jsfiddle.net/2GJrW/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".border").hover(function(){
            $(this).animate({ 

                borderBottom :'2px solid #3399FF',
                width:'46%' 


            }, 500 );
        });





    });
```